# Error in set_user_by_token.rb in deviseTokenAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using DeviseTokenAuth for authentication in rails api.It gives error in update
user

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `enable_standard_devise_support' for DeviseTokenAuth:Module):
app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb:35:in `set_user_by_token'
```

On this line

```
if DeviseTokenAuth.enable_standard_devise_support
devise_warden_user = warden.user(rc.to_s.underscore.to_sym)
 if devise_warden_user && devise_warden_user.tokens[@client_id].nil?
 @used_auth_by_token = false
 @resource = devise_warden_user
 @resource.create_new_auth_token
 end
end
```

Routes is

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do

  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: '/auth'
  resources :users

end
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
   #everything is in comments there
end
```

Comment: have you installed devise gem?

Comment: yes install devise also

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb` file and  `devise_token_auth.rb` files?

Comment: See I update it...n there is no devise_token_auth.rb file

Comment: Did you include `include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User` in your `user.rb` ?

Comment: Have you followed this? https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#can-i-use-this-gem-alongside-standard-devise

Comment: Yes do by followin this

Comment: then why is there no `devise_token_auth.rb`  file? It will be in the initializers

Comment: Updated...kindly see now :)

Comment: can you add `config.enable_standard_devise_support = true` in `devise_token_auth.rb`

Comment: It gives error undefined method :(

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the configs?

Comment: Yes on restarting get this error